# iOS indicate to user they can use a swipe gesture

Tags: mobile, ios, games, indicator

I have a puzzle game for iOS where the user can swipe left to skip the current puzzle and try another one.  They can also swipe right to view previous puzzles.  However, I'm having trouble coming up with a way to indicate this feature to users.

Arrows on the left/right side seem like they would get in the way of some larger puzzles.  Here is a screenshot of the main puzzle screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I will handle that is making the puzzle follow your finger...

and add buttons at the bottom and a indicator in the bottom center

[image]

[image]